# How to execute admin level command via remote login without typing password?

Tags: catalina, ssh, script, sudo, administrator

I would like to allow a remote script to access my Mac (Catalina 10.15.2) at the root level.

I know that I can enable keyboard-less access at the user level, by using publickey authentication, via ssh. This is handy, because it allows me to remotely execute scripts on my Mac, over ssh, from a script running on another host.

Is there a way to execute root commands, via ssh, without typing a password, without enabling login for the root account?

Are there other authentication methods for sudo, aside from password?

Comment: Did you see this question? [proper way to sudo over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310299/proper-way-to-sudo-over-ssh)

Comment: Yes. The solutions don't work for me on Catalina 10.15.2. There must be some differences between sudo on linux and mac os. Seems like the Mac sudo will not accept a password piped to it.